# What could be causing google sites to show source in just Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, google-docs

Some websites just go horribly weird in Firefox, but whenever I search I cannot find anyone else with the same problem. 
It isn't fonts, it isn't character encoding.

What I see is the real website flash on screen then it redirects to showing me the javascript source, like this:

[image: screenshot of problem]

If I press `Esc` in that fraction of a second, then I get to see the real page.

That is often good enough, but I don't get any embedded content. In the above case, after trying the same URL in chrome and opera, I can see it is an embedded pdf.

So, embedded content is triggering some problem. It only happens with google sites (as in, websites that have been made from google documents - google search, gmail, etc. are all fine).  I doubt it is needing a plugin, as chrome and opera work out of the box.

Firefox 55, 64-bit linux; but this has been happening a couple of years, so back to the Firefox 40s, at least, I imagine.

Comment: Do you have the same in private mode? Sometimes such behaviour occurs because of cache issues. You also could refresh firefox settings: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Answer (score 1):

Started going through my add-ons, flash, etc. systematically. Narrowed it down to this plugin:
  http://matagus.github.io/remove-google-redirects-addon/

Ironically I'd started to suspect that plugin was no longer doing its job, so was going to disable it anyway!